# Scripts in body tag aren't loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load up angular inside my body tag but for some reason nothing is getting loaded, when I check the resources panel it only contains files from the head. If I move all this stuff to the head It shows up in resources and its loaded, but when in the body, it's unloaded.

```
<body>
    <section ui-view=""></section>
    <!-- inject:js-->
    <script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject-->
    <!-- inject:files:js-->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject-->
</body>
```

What's going on here? why is this not being loaded into the page?

I'm using `gulp` and `gulp-webserver` but that shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: obvious question is "are the paths correct?"

Comment: if they weren't when I put them into the head they wouldn't load...

Comment: what do the inject comment tags do?

Comment: They are from gulp-inject, they are what generate the tags(script/link) based off of the files that need to get put in. They aren't what is causing this though

Comment: just curious, try removing `/` -- i use local paths and it works fine in my index.html file.

Comment: You do know that in web context '/' refers to root folder, removing the / doesn't and won't make a difference, again, if it was to do with the path it wouldn't work in my <head></head>.

Comment: Just for curiosity. have you tried with `type='text/javascript'` inside `script` tag while using it inside `body` tag? also can you try `<script ......... onload='alert("loaded!");'></script>`?

Comment: The onload event never gets hit and the type='text/javascript'(which as far as I know is unesccisary now) does nothing :(

Comment: So you're saying there are no errors in the console and no network traffic indicating the files are fetched by the browser at all?

Comment: Nope no traffic and no errors. If i set paths with a prefix of http://localhost:9000 it works in the body but that shouldn't be the case?

Comment: I do know that `/` refers to root. But angular or gulp or `ui-view` or whatever that is could be mucking with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<base href="http://localhost:9000">
```

was my problem. A difficult find, it was

```
<base href="localhost:9000">
```

before making the root directory obsolete!

Thanks for the help all!